# InnoDB - Fulltext (match against) extremely slow, wrong indexes?

Tags: mysql, innodb, amazon-rds, full-text-search

I've recently migrated my myisam-tables to InnoDB and some things are a bit weird for me. For starters, the indexes looks a bit different (and maybe is the reason why the new InnoDB-implementation is slow)?

The table holds 1,2m unique items.

Database: Mysql 8+,
Aws RDS

```
CREATE TABLE `books` (
  `isbn` bigint NOT NULL,
  `title` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci NOT NULL,
  `text` text CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci,
  `created` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci;


ALTER TABLE `books`
  ADD UNIQUE KEY `isbn` (`isbn`),
  ADD KEY `created` (`created`);
ALTER TABLE `books` ADD FULLTEXT KEY `fulltext_title_text` (`title`,`text`);
ALTER TABLE `books` ADD FULLTEXT KEY `title` (`title`);
ALTER TABLE `books` ADD FULLTEXT KEY `text` (`text`);
COMMIT;
```

And a typical and slow query:

```
SELECT `b`.`isbn`,
    MATCH(`b`.`title`) 
       AGAINST(:keywords IN BOOLEAN MODE) AS `score_title`,
    MATCH(`b`.`text`) 
       AGAINST(:keywords IN BOOLEAN MODE) AS `score_text`
  FROM `books` AS `b`
  WHERE MATCH(`b`.`title`, `b`.`text`)
           AGAINST(:keywords IN BOOLEAN MODE)
  GROUP BY `b`.`isbn`
  HAVING (`score_title` + `score_text`) > 0
  ORDER BY (`score_title` * 1.5) +
           (`score_text`) DESC
  LIMIT 0, 20

---
:keywords = "+Administrator*"
```

When inspecting the new table, I can see this about my indexes:
[image]

Also:
[image]

Any suggestion how to speed up the query?

Comment: Does it run as fast without the `GROUP BY`?  And get the same results?  Ditto for the `HAVING`?  How many rows match "+Administrator*"?  (Remove the`LIMIT` and use `COUNT(*)`.)

Comment: Hi Rick! How do you mean 'use COUNT(*)' ? Can you give me any example with abouve query? I understand the rest. My initial thought is that something is wrongly setup with the indexes..

Comment: You're surely wasting time trying to group by a unique key.  I think you can forget about the having too, since it corresponds to the where clause.  I think @RickJames meant that you could do a "select count(*)" iso. individual rows, to know the number of books matching.